# Python download big number files Time Out HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-requests, urllib

I want to use Python3 to download a lot of images.
I was using urllib.request.urlretrieve to download,and set time out with socket.setdefaulttimeout
And I think it won't output time out error,but ....

Here my code

```
import threading
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(60.0)
def multi_thread():
        for file in self.url_list:
            t = threading.Thread(target=fun, args=[file])
            threads_task.append(t)
        for task in threads_task:
            task.start()
        for task in threads_task:

  def fun():
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Error:

```
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway 
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
<urlopen error [WinError 10060]
 <urlopen error [WinError 10060]
 <urlopen error [WinError 10060]
```

The problem is that I used the code to download 10 images,it works well.
But 1000+ images ,too many time out.maybe hundreds of time out.

Then I changed my idea ,drop multithreading,download images one by one,it works pretty good,and only two timeout errors.

So how can i deal with it?
Really need your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your number of threads. For 1000+ files, you are running 1000+ concurrent threads, that cause the target server to overload. You need to limit concurrent threads. You can do this by [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(60.0)

def multi_thread():
        pool = Pool(processes=4)        # 4 concurrent processes/threads
        pool.map(fun, self.url_list)    # apply method 'fun' to all the items in 'self.url_list'

  def fun(file):
        url, filename = file.url, file.filename
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

In this way, your all 1000+ files will be downloaded in multiple threads/subprocesses, but there will only be 4 concurrent threads.

Comment: I got it ,1000+ images create too many threads,really thanks.